# What does the {-y,x} in this equation mean?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

What does the {-y,x} in this equation mean?

```
.5 {-y,x}/(x^2+y^2)
```

Comment: Evaluate your expressions and see what you get. Maybe try `{x,y}+5` to get a hint. Note that `()` and `{}` have utterly different meanings.

Comment: `{-y, x}` is a List. Many operations such as Times, Plus, Divide, etc. have the attribute [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) and exploiting this attribute can simplify code. Without this attribute, the expression would have to be written as `0.5 #/(x^2+y^2)& /@ {-y, x}` or `Table[0.5 t/(x^2+y^2), {t, {-y, x}}]`or some other equivalent.

Comment: It probably represents a vector field in the plane. It is the velocity field of a uniformly rotating plate with an angular velocity of one radian per second.  The whole expression is an irrotational (curl = 0) rotatory flow in which inner circles rotate faster than outer circles.

Comment: `Normalize[Cross[{x,y}]]/2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.5 {-y, x}/(x^2 + y^2) // TraditionalForm` to see that `.5 {-y, x}/(x^2 + y^2)` can be use to express the vector value function.

$$\left(\frac{-0.5y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{0.5x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

and actually,`{-y, x}/(x^2 + y^2)` is the gradient of the function `ArcTan[y/x]` or `ArcTan[x,y]`

```
Grad[ArcTan[x, y], {x, y}]
Grad[ArcTan[y/x], {x, y}] // Simplify
(* {-(y/(x^2 + y^2)), x/(x^2 + y^2)} *)
```

```
GraphicsRow[{VectorPlot[{-(y/(x^2 + y^2)), x/(
    x^2 + y^2)}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]], 
  VectorPlot[
   Grad[ArcTan[x, y], {x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]}]
```

[image]